# Computer slows down during downloads

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, performance, hp-pavilion, dpc

Last week, I reinstalled my company laptop, a HP Pavilion dv7-6b22ed. Everything was installed okay, but there is one issue I can't solve: whenever I download a file, be it a several hunderd MB file or a rather big web page, the computer slows down. It expresses itself as stuttering audio, a slow moving mouse pointer and in almost being able to see that screen components are being drawn (e.g.: selections in comboboxes appear one option at a time). As soon as the download finishes, the computer goes back to its regular speed again. I don't have problems with my download speed, which is around 17Mbps over wireless.

I've installed all of the drivers from the HP site (http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4132&lc=nl&cc=nl&dlc=nl&sw_lang=&product=5191530#N189 - it's a dutch page, because I can't seem to find that make of laptop on HPs site when I have another language) and Windows updates, ran multiple assist tools including HPs Support Assistant and Intel's Driver Update Utility. According to both tools, everything is up-to-date.
The only update I could not install is the BIOS update. It results in a blue screen with the error code `DRIVER_VERIFIER_DETECTED_VIOLATION`, which I assume means that the driver itself is faulty.

It does not *seem* to be I/O in general: moving several GB of data from my SATA drive to my SSD drive doesn't slow the machine at all.

I don't believe that Windows 8.1 is the culprit, because I had Windows 8 installed before the reinstallation and that worked just fine and without slowing down. I was thinking that it might be the download speed which slows it down, but I don't know hot to throttle it to test that.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: looks like you have DPC issues. Trace them with xperf: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140263

Comment: Looks like a DPC issue with ndis.sys. I've tried installing the Windows 8 drivers on HPs site, but to no avail. The Win7 drivers don't seem to work, either. I've tried uninstalling the wireless driver so I could install it myself, but after a reboot it's back, as if I never removed it. Where do I go from here?

Comment: which network card do you have? Post the HW ID which you can see in device manager.

Comment: According to Device Manager, I have an Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1030. According to the specs on HPs site: 'Intel 802.11 bgn'. Hardware IDs: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_008B&SUBSYS_53158086&REV_34, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_008B&SUBSYS_53158086, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_008B&CC_028000 and PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_008B&CC_0280.

Comment: get the latest driver from Intel.com (not HP) and look if it fixes the issue

Comment: I downloaded version 16.11.0 from https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProdId=3314, but still the same problem. I skipped the software for Bluetooth (v 17.1.1406.01). According to device manager, version 15.4.1.1 has been installed and according to the Intel website, version 16.10.1. Redownloading and reinstalling doesn't yield a different version number. 
Would the Windows 7 drivers work? Or is there something inherently wrong with my Windows 8.1 install?

Comment: upload the generated ETL file (zip it first to reduce the file size)

Comment: https://copy.com/8xqhPJhhbJA41EAQ - Please let me know when you've downloaded the archive so I can remove it. Please let me know if this file suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have activated [Driver Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and causes this the DPC issues.

[image]

Simply remove it and reboot. The issue should be gone. If you still have spikes, capture and upload a new trace.

Comment: Awesome! That worked. How did you figure that out?

Comment: I saw this in the callstack. I highlighted some Driver Verifier calls in the picture.